# Laravel logging to a custom channel

Tags: laravel, logging

I am trying to log certain application processes into a log in Laravel. I created a  log channel in logging.php

```
'report-log' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/report-log.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
```

Now I am using

```
Log::channel('report-log')->info('Something happened!');
```

This is not creating any log file(since the file is not present initially) or make any log entry.

Comment: Check user `www-data` or `_www` for writing access to `storage/logs` directory. Because it should create it automatically.

Comment: @KeitelDOG am actually working in a windows machine and have full access to the project directory. Is there anything else I need to configure in laravel for logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by creating a file 'report-log.log' under logs. It was automatically not getting created for me so I created it and the logs started appearing.

Comment: Good it works for you. It was probably a permission issue on the directory for your apache user, not your own user browsing the windows folders. Or maybe it's a windows behavior only cause they are automatically created in all Laravel projects that I've used them in Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good. Which Operating System do you use? You may be dealing with permission problem. You might want to give Ubuntu `www-data` or Mac `_www` enough permission to create the log file.

```
sudo chown -R www-data storage/logs
```

Or you can put `www-data` as group also and give write permission to that group

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage/logs
sudo chmod -R 755 storage/logs
```

Or if you want to make sure it's not permission related, give everyone all access and after DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE IT BACK TO NORMAL AS IT'S NOT A SECURE PRACTICE :

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 storage/logs
```